# How to read a .docx file in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, phpword, phpoffice

I have a laravel app, version 5.39. I'm using phpoffice/phpword 0.15 library.

I'm trying to upload a .docx file and read its content.

I tried this:

```
    $phpWord = IOFactory::createReader('Word2007')->load($request->file('file')->path());

    $text = '';
    foreach($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {
        foreach($section->getElements() as $element) {
            if(method_exists($element,'getText')) {
                $text = $text . $element->getText();
            }
        }
    }
    Log::info($text);
```

But it logs an empty string, no errors.

I also tried this, but the result is the same:

```
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $newFileName = time() . '_' . str_replace(' ', '_', $fileName);
    $filePath = $file->storeAs('app', $newFileName);
    $realPath = Storage::path($filePath);
    $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Word2007');
    $phpWord = $reader->load($realPath);
    $text = '';
    $sections = $phpWord->getSections();
    foreach ($sections as $section) {
        $elements = $section->getElements();
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $text .= $element->getText();
        }
    }

    Log::info($text);
```

My html file looks like this

```
    <form id="file-upload-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Upload and read Word file</button>
    </form>

    <script>

        $(function() {
            $('#file-upload-form').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/upload-file",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        // Update the page with the text from the Word file
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        // Handle the error
                    }
                });
            });
        });
     <script>
```

Is there a way to read the content of the file?